# How to use DictionaryModelBinder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core 2.2
[DictionaryModelBinder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.binders.dictionarymodelbinder-2?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetValue")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetValue(
[ModelBinder(BinderType=typeof(DictionaryModelBinder<string,string>))] 
    IDictionary<string, string> id)
{
     return Ok();
}
```

Error:

> InvalidOperationException: Multiple constructors accepting all given
>   argument types have been found in type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.DictionaryModelBinder`2[System.String,System.String]'.
>   There should only be one applicable constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some source code analyze, I found the way to use [`DictionaryModelBinder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.binders.dictionarymodelbinder-2?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

```
[HttpGet("GetValue")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetValue([FromQuery] IDictionary<string, string> id)
{
     return Ok();
}
```

and the request should be

`api/GetValue?id.Key1=Value1&id.Key2=Value2&id.Key3=Value3`

(OR)

`api/GetValue?id[Key1]=Value1&id[Key2]=Value2&id[Key3]=Value3`

**Note**

- No need to explicitly use [`ModelBinderAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinderattribute). This is added by default
- We need to add [`FromQueryAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute) for the parameter